# Per Monitor Awareness is returning unexpected results

Tags: winapi, dpi

I try to modify an application to support per monitor awareness.

Here the results:

I start my application with 96dpi. The test window is the following:

[image]

You see the handmade Switchbox on top returning the fontsize of the text (9.75 pt)

After I switch to 120dpi with the running application

[image]

You see, because FontSize is not modified, the pt remains to 9.75 pt

Now I start in 120dpi a second instance of the test application:

[image]

You see the fontsize is now returned with 9.6pt (which is indeed lower than 9.75pt), but the font is displayed bigger than on the first instance displaying the font with 9.75pt.

It seems, the font creation on the second instance is somehow influenced by the Start dpi and fonts with nearly same pt (which is depending of DPI of course) are displayed different.

What is going wrong here?

Code sequence on start of the child window (SwitchBox)

```
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext dpiPER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2
SetThreadDpiHostingBehavior DPI_HOSTING_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT
SetDialogControlDpiChangeBehavior UserControl.hwnd, DCDC_DISABLE_FONT_UPDATE Or DCDC_DISABLE_RELAYOUT, DCDC_DISABLE_FONT_UPDATE Or DCDC_DISABLE_RELAYOUT
dpi = GetDpiForWindow(UserControl.hwnd)

mDPIFactor = dpi / 96

mhTheme = OpenThemeDataForDpi(UserControl.hwnd, StrPtr(m_sClass), dpi)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: This is absolutely crazy. Running an instance in 96dpi and switching to 120dpi and running an application with 120dpi with different GUI results. There are some other differences when you watch the radio buttons drawn with OpenThemeDataForDPI draw correctly when switching from 96 to 120 dpi, but with artefacts when started directly with 120dpi

Comment: Are you handling the [WM_DPICHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged) message?

Comment: I believe there is a missing code sequence maybe for correct settings. Who has experiences with it?

Comment: Child Windows get WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT
    Case WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT
        Dim mDPI As Long
        
        mDPI = GetDpiForWindow(hwnd)
        
        mDPIFactor = mDPI / 96
        
        CloseThemeData mhTheme
        mhTheme = OpenThemeDataForDpi(UserControl.hwnd, StrPtr(m_sClass), mDPI)

Comment: But when application is starting, the WM_DPICHANGEDXXX messages are not occurring of course. You get them when you change the desktop or you move a window to a monitor with another DPI